# C++ using "cout" outside of main function?

Tags: c++

I don't know if I am just using the wrong keywords.. but I can't find an answer on google. Not can I wrap my feeble mind around my error.

This is a simple demonstration of the error:

```
#include <iostream>

//std::cout << "hello";

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling/running this I receive this error:

> main.cpp:3:6: error: 'cout' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

However, if I remove the first `cout` line, and just allow the program to execute the one inside of the main function, it works just fine.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: In most programs, code needs to be in a function in order to be executed.

Comment: executable code goes in functions

Answer (score 5):

You cannot run code outside functions in C++. The compiler only expect variable declarations outside functions and, thus, expects std::cout to be a type, which it is not.

Comment: "cannot run code" is vague. The syntax does not permit *statements* outside function definitions.

Comment: Why of course you can. Just make the code a part of a variable initialisation. `std::ostream& foo = std::cout << "maga";`